Smallest root of a degree 3 polynomial
Is it true that the smallest root $t$ of the polynomial
$$
20 t^3 - 30 t^2 + (12 - 4 \cos^2 \alpha - 4 \cos^2 \beta - 4 \cos^2 \gamma) t + \cos^2 \alpha + \cos^2 \beta + \cos^2 \gamma - 2 \cos \alpha \cos \beta \cos \gamma - 1
$$
is always no greater than $\frac{1}{5}$ for all $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in [0,\pi]$ with $\alpha + \beta \geq \gamma$, $\alpha + \gamma \geq \beta$, $\beta + \gamma \geq \alpha$, and $\alpha + \beta + \gamma \leq 2\pi$?
Thanks a lot for any helpful answer.

I have performed numerous computations but have not found any counterexample.

This looks like a characteristic polynomial of a certain $3\times 3$ matrix, is not it arised this way?

@FedorPetrov It may not be completely that, but do you have any insights on finding the answer regarding the algebraic or analytic property of polynomials? Thanks.

I am suspicious about conditions on $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$: the restriction $\alpha+\beta+\gamma\le 2\pi$ seems useless, since if it does not hold, you may replace $\alpha, \beta$ to $\pi-\alpha, \pi-\beta$ and the polynomial does not change. Are you sure that we do not require additionally that $\alpha+\beta\ge \gamma$ etc?

@FedorPetrov Thank you for your comment. It has been revised. Thanks.

@FedorPetrov  Do you have any insights on finding the answer? Thanks.

I don't understand the close votes. The problem does not seem quite trivial, and it could possibly have arisen in some research.

I removed the tag "root-systems" as it is not relevant for the problem. Regarding root systems, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_system

@IosifPinelis I think it's an excellent question and have certainly not downvoted/closevoted, but I suspect the folks who are are hoping for more context; it's clear that this polynomial comes from somewhere rather than appearing like Venus from the waves, and it would be helpful/interesting/etc. to know its origins.

I added a proof which requires no machine calculation and is cleaner (in my opinion) than the two proofs already posted. Moreover, it shows that there is a real root not exceeding $(5-\sqrt{15})/10$, and this estimate is optimal.

This proof is similar to River Li's, but it requires no machine calculation. Also, we will show more, namely that the original polynomial has three real roots, the smallest of which is at most
$$u:=\frac{5-\sqrt{15}}{10}=0.11270166\dotsc$$
This estimate is sharp, because in case of $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=\pi/2$, the polynomial is
$$20t^3-30t^2+12t-1=20\left(t-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(t-\frac{5-\sqrt{15}}{10}\right)\left(t-\frac{5+\sqrt{15}}{10}\right).$$
We turn to the proof. With the notation
$$Q:=\frac{\cos^2\alpha+\cos^2\beta+\cos^2\gamma}{3}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
R:=\cos\alpha\cos\beta\cos\gamma,$$
the polynomial in the original post equals
$$p(t):=20t^3-30t^2+12(1-Q)t+(3Q-2R-1).$$
The coefficients of this cubic polynomial are
$$a:=20,\qquad b:=-30,\qquad c:=12(1-Q),\qquad d:=3Q-2R-1,$$
hence its discriminant equals
\begin{align*}
\Delta\ := \ & 18 a b c d - 4 b^3 d + b^2 c^2 - 4 a c^3 - 27 a^2 d^2 \\ 
\ = \ & 2160 (1 + 12 Q + 3 Q^2 + 64 Q^3 - 60 Q R - 20 R^2).
\end{align*}
Here $2 QR\leq Q^2+R^2$, and also $R^2\leq Q^3$ by the AM-GM inequality, whence
\begin{align*}
\Delta/2160 \ 
& \geq \ 1 + 12 Q + 3 Q^2 + 64 Q^3 - 30 Q^2 - 50 R^2 \\
& \geq \ 1 + 12 Q - 27 Q^2 + 14 Q^3 \\
& = \ (Q-1)^2(1+14Q) \\
& \geq \ 0.
\end{align*}
So $p(t)$ has three real roots (counted with multiplicity), and the same is true of the shifted polynomial
$$p(u+t)=20t^3-6\sqrt{15}t^2+6(1-2Q)t+\left(6\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}Q-3Q-2R\right).$$
It remains to show that this new polynomial $p(u+t)$ has a nonpositive root $t$. If this is not the case, then $p(u+t)$ has three positive roots (counted with multiplicity), hence in particular
$$1-2Q>0>6\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}Q-3Q-2R.$$
However, this is a contradiction, because it would yield that
$$Q^3\geq R^2>\left(3\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}-\frac{3}{2}\right)^2 Q^2\geq\frac{1}{2}Q^2\geq Q^3.$$

Nice. It is a solution without calculus.

@RiverLi Thank you. I have now sharpened the conclusion slightly.

Nice, without complicated computation, also the condition is redundant.

@RiverLi Thanks again. I further simplified the proof, now the original polynomial is only shifted once.

Write $a,b,c$ instead of $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$. Let $p(t)$ be the polynomial in question. Let
$$u:=\cos^2a+\cos^2b+\cos^2c,\quad v:=\cos a\,\cos b\,\cos c,$$
$$t_*:=\frac{1}{30} \left(15-\sqrt{15} \sqrt{4 u+3}\right).$$
Then
$$0\le u\le3,\quad v\le(u/3)^{3/2},$$
$$\begin{aligned}p(t_*)&=\frac{(4 u+3)^{3/2}}{3 \sqrt{15}}-u-2 v \\
&\ge\frac{(4 u+3)^{3/2}}{3 \sqrt{15}}-u-2 (u/3)^{3/2} \\ 
&=:g(u)\ge g(3)=0
\end{aligned}$$
(the latter inequality holds because $u=3$ is the only critical point of $g$ and $g(0)>0$),
$$t_*>1/5\implies u<3/5,$$
$$\begin{aligned}p(1/5)&=\frac{1}{25} (5 u-50 v+9) \\ 
&\ge\frac{1}{25} (5 u-50(u/3)^{3/2}+9) \\ 
&=:h(u)\ge\min(h(0),h(3/5)) \\ 
&>0 \text{ if }0\le u<3/5 
\end{aligned}$$
(the 2nd inequality in the latter display holds because $h$ is concave).
So, $p(\min(t_*,1/5))\ge0$.
Also, $p(-\infty+)=-\infty<0$.
Thus, $p(t)=0$ for some real $t\le1/5$. $\quad\Box$

Note that no conditions on $a,b,c$ (that is, on $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$) were needed or used here.

"Claims (1) and (2) can be verified algorithmically" -- technically, the initial claim can also be verified algorithmically (by writing all the conditions in terms of sines and cosines and using Tarski--Seidenberg). I think what you implicitly mean is that they "can be verified algorithmically before the heat death of the Universe".

@AlekseiKulikov : You are quite right. I have further simplified the expressions for $t_$ and $p(t_)$ to reduce the total Mathematica execution time to under 0.5 sec.

The proof is now much simpler and without using Mathematica.

The new argument looks extremely condensed, even the logic is hard to follow, it would benefit from a few english words I think. Anyway, if I understood it right, in the middle you claim that $g(u) \ge g(3)$ for $0 \le u \le 3$ -- why is that true? (you also claim that $h(u) \ge \max(h(0), h(3/5))$ which is just straight up false, but I assume you've meant $\min$ there and not $\max$, which I managed to convince myself in)

@AlekseiKulikov : I have added two details here. Please let me know if more details are needed. Also, of course, here we need $\min$ rather than $\max$.

Yes, the new argument is ok, but do you have a nicer argument for $3$ being the only critical point of $g$, other than "just take the derivative and solve the equation, high-school style".

@AlekseiKulikov : Such a quest, with such a rather simple but apparently unremarkable function $g$, would look rather strange to me.

@Iosif Pinelis Thank you for your answer. May I ask how you found $t_{}$? And, are there other  $t_{}$'s that are significantly different and would work? Thanks.

@Venus : $t_$ is the only critical point of $p(t)$ that is $\le1/5$. I have not tried other $t_$'s.

@Venus : Do you have a further response to this answer?

Solution.
With the substitution $t = \frac15 + s$, the equation is written as
$$f(s) := 20s^3 - 18s^2 + qs - r = 0, \tag{1}$$
where
\begin{align*}
    q &:= \frac{12}{5} - 4 \cos^2 \alpha - 4 \cos^2 \beta - 4 \cos^2 \gamma, \\
    r &:= - \frac{9}{25} - \frac15\cos^2 \alpha - \frac15 \cos^2 \beta - \frac15 \cos^2 \gamma + 2 \cos \alpha \cos \beta \cos \gamma.
\end{align*}
First, let us prove that (1) has three real roots. It suffices to prove that discriminant of $f$ is non-negative, or equivalently
$$g(\cos \alpha, \cos \beta, \cos \gamma) \ge 0,$$
where
\begin{align*}
    g(a, b, c) &:= 64\,{a}^{6}+192\,{a}^{4}{b}^{2}+192\,{a}^{4}{c}^{2}+192\,{a}^{2}{b}^{4
    }\\
&\qquad -156\,{a}^{2}{b}^{2}{c}^{2}+192\,{a}^{2}{c}^{4} +64\,{b}^{6}+192\,{b}^
    {4}{c}^{2}\\
    &\qquad +192\,{b}^{2}{c}^{4} +64\,{c}^{6}-540\,{a}^{3}bc -540\,a{b}^{3
    }c\\
&\qquad -540\,ab{c}^{3}+9\,{a}^{4} +18\,{a}^{2}{b}^{2}+18\,{a}^{2}{c}^{2}+9\,
    {b}^{4}\\
    &\qquad +18\,{b}^{2}{c}^{2}+9\,{c}^{4}+108\,{a}^{2}+108\,{b}^{2}+108\,{
        c}^{2}+27.
\end{align*}
We can prove that $g(a, b, c) \ge 0$ for all real numbers $a, b, c$ (this is verified by Mathematica). The desired result follows.
Second, we prove that (1) does not have three positive real roots.
Assume, for the sake of contradiction, that (1) has three positive real roots. Then we have $q > 0, r > 0$.
However, we can prove that
$\frac54 r + \frac{3}{16}q \le 0$ that is
$$- \cos^2 \alpha - \cos^2 \beta - \cos^2 \gamma + \frac52 \cos \alpha \cos \beta \cos \gamma \le 0. \tag{2}$$
(2) is true since
$$\cos^2 \alpha + \cos^2 \beta + \cos^2 \gamma \ge 3\sqrt[3]{\cos^2 \alpha  \cos^2 \beta  \cos^2 \gamma}$$
$$\ge 3|\cos \alpha \cos \beta \cos \gamma| \ge \frac52 \cos \alpha \cos \beta \cos \gamma.$$ Contradiction. Thus, the claim is proved.
Thus, (1) has at least one real root $s \le 0$.
We are done.

It is confusing to write $f(a,b,c)$ when you already use the notation $f(s)$.

@GHfromMO Thanks. I will edit.

Thank you for your answer. Are verification and proof the same? Since you said that you "can prove that $g(a, b, c) \ge 0$ for all real numbers $a, b, c$," could you please show the proof? Thanks.

@Venus I think proof is referred to as a human verifiable proof of the inequalities (sometimes we use computer to motivate the proof, but the proof itself is verifiable by hand usually), while verification is to use computer to verify the inequalities without showing the steps.

@Venus When $r < 0$, then $f(0) > 0$ and there is a negative root. Can you find them such that $r < 0$?

@RiverLi  Then could the computer or could you have the computer show the steps? Thanks.

@Venus My proof for $g(a,b,c)\ge 0$ for all reals is complicated. Actually I hope to see a simple proof for the statement that (1) has three real roots.

@RiverLi I added a simple proof that (1) has three real roots. See my response below.
